# Actual meaning of equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium, concentration

What is actually meant by that concentration of reactants and products remain constant in equilibrium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

t.c is right, but to expand on it, equilibrium means that a reaction is still occurring, i.e. reactants are converting to products and products are converting to reactants, but they're doing so at the same rate so there's no net change in the concentrations of any of the components. Contrast this with a metastable system, in which concentrations of components may be remaining the same, but the two aren't interconverting because of a large kinetic barrier.

Comment: Does it mean that same amount of quantity is converted to product as the quantity as is converted to reactants after attaining equilibrium ?

Comment: Over a given period of time, yes. That's what same rate means. Rate = change in concentration/change in time.

Answer (score 2):

For an equation
$\ce{Reactant <=> Product}$, at equilibrium, the rate of reactants forming products is the same as the rate of products converting back to reactants. Therefore, the concentration of products and reactants remain constant.